# Why does `rsync` not require super-user privileges?

Tags: rsync

From manpage of `rsync`:

> Some of the additional features of rsync are:
>
> - does not require super-user privileges

Is it correct that what `rsync` process needs is

- read permission on every source file,
- and write permission on every destination file?

Any thing incorrect or missing?

Why does the manpage say that `rsync` "does not require super-user privileges"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's not a daemon, works as long as you have permissions to read (origin) and write (destination) as you stated, and it (somewhat) allows you to preserve ownership/attributes in the copy, even if you are not root or the user at the destination machine (read about --super and --fake-super, for this to work the destination has to be compatible with the ACLs).

From the same manpage of rsync:

```
 --fake-super
      When this option is enabled, rsync simulates super-user  activi‐
      ties  by  saving/restoring the privileged attributes via special
      extended attributes that are attached to each file (as  needed).
      This  includes  the  file’s  owner  and  group (if it is not the
      default), the file’s device info (device  &  special  files  are
      created  as  empty  text files), and any permission bits that we
      won’t allow to be set on the real file (e.g.  the real file gets
      u-s,g-s,o-t  for  safety) or that would limit the owner’s access
      (since the real super-user can always access/change a file,  the
      files  we  create can always be accessed/changed by the creating
      user).  This option also handles ACLs (if --acls was  specified)
      and non-user extended attributes (if --xattrs was specified).

      This  is  a  good way to backup data without using a super-user,
      and to store ACLs from incompatible systems.
```

Edit and to clarify: *"Does not require super-user privileges"* doesn't mean it's not useful to be super-user. It just means it will work (mostly) anyway.